# Orderby Wordpress users

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

Currently I have this code but would like to `orderby` in descending order reputation_p's value.

Any ideas? I am also using pagination

```
<?php 

    $no=24;// total no of author to display

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if($paged==1){
      $offset=0;  
    }else {
       $offset= ($paged-1)*$no;
    }


    // Foreach loop 

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'frontend_vendor',  'number' => $no, 'offset' => $offset ) );
       if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this wordpress doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) you need to add the `orderby` query to your array

```
     $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'frontend_vendor',  'number' => $no, 'offset' => $offset, 'orderby' => 'reputation_p', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

Comment: Thank you nick very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just you add `order by` query to your code like:
 
`$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array( 
        'role' => 'frontend_vendor',

        'number' => $no, 
        'offset' => $offset, 
        'orderby' => 'reputation_p', 
        'order' => 'DESC'
     )
);`

for more information check wordpress documentation for **WP_User_Query()**

Comment: Thank you androidzoneus this works better now sorry i am still learning :)

Comment: WC @Tony Harris :)